# Compiler design, creating a language. How?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages

The [Dragon book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3a_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)
is a famous book for designing a compiler. Is there another book like that or a great article about that? And what're the keywords about compilers? I wanna know how a new language is created.

Comment: you can start with [Let's Build a Compiler](http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/)

Comment: duplicate of [Learning to write a compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler)

Comment: Creating a new language is different from making a compiler for a language.  This question could get focussed answers if you break it into two different questions, one for building a compiler and another for creating a new language.

Comment: I meant designing compiler for a new language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great book on implementing functional languages, just a little bit outdated: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/pj-lester-book/

Another useful source (on languages in general, not just on compilation) is [http://www.amazon.com/Theories-Programming-Languages-John-Reynolds/dp/0521594146](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521594146)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to go .NET:
[http://www.amazon.com/Build-Your-NET-Language-Compiler/dp/1590591348](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590591348)

Answer (score 0):

Writing Compilers and Interpreters, by Ronald Mack, is an excellent "practical" text that walks you through the important parts of a compiler and how they are constructed.  The original edition was C, the second edition was C++, and the current edition is Java.

It is a much easier read than the Dragon Book.

Answer (score 0):

This book gives you an overview of programming paradigms and may be useful:
[http://www.amazon.com/Concepts-Techniques-Models-Computer-Programming/dp/0262220695](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262220695)